# Bing Maps REST services JSON deserialziation error

Tags: c#, json, rest, bing-maps, bing-api

I am trying to obtain driving directions via the Bing Maps REST services.  The response seems to be going through, but when deserializing to JSON with the provided Data Contracts the following exception is thrown:

> Element ':item' contains data from a type that maps to the name 'http://schemas.microsoft.com/search/local/ws/rest/v1:Route'. The deserializer has no knowledge of any type that maps to this name. Consider using a DataContractResolver or add the type corresponding to 'Route' to the list of known types - for example, by using the KnownTypeAttribute attribute or by adding it to the list of known types passed to DataContractSerializer.

The MSDN link I am working off of is available at:  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj819168.aspx

I have copied the necessary DataContracts from the link on the bottom of the sample, but can't figure out why the exception is occuring when deserializing.  Here is the code I am executing:

```
private async void btnGetRoute_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
            string locationFrom = "100 Commonwealth Ave Boston MA";
            string locationTo = "100 Yawkey Way Boston MA";
            string url = string.Format("http://dev.virtualearth.net/REST/V1/Routes/Driving?wp.0={0}&wp.1={1}&key={2}", locationFrom, locationTo, ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["BingMapsKey"]);
            Uri drivingRouteRequest = new Uri(url);

            Response response = await GetResponse(drivingRouteRequest);
    }

    private async Task<Response> GetResponse(Uri uri)
    {
        HttpClient client = new System.Net.Http.HttpClient();
        var response = await client.GetAsync(uri);

        using (var stream = await response.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync())
        {
            DataContractJsonSerializer ser = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(Response));
            return ser.ReadObject(stream) as Response;
        }
    }
```

Any thoughts?

Comment: Any progress on this?
I noticed the same issue
[here][1].
Tom

  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25297238/bing-rest-api-get-route-from-response-resourcesets

Comment: @Tom no... We use Telerik.  I was able to get driving directions through them instead.  I haven't tried this method again so can't provide anything further right now.

Answer (score 1):

The Bing Maps team is aware of that and have updated documentation coming soon. The issue is that a new object is  being returned, where as before we only knew the property name. I have an updated set of data contracts in one of my projects which you can find here: http://mapstoolbox.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#Microsoft.Maps.Spatialtoolbox/Source/Microsoft.Maps.SpatialToolbox.Core/Bing/Services/RestServices.cs

Comment: Is the information that the updated documentation will be coming soon available via a link somewhere on an MSDN site or did you obtain your information from a private support ticket?

Comment: I'm on the Bing Maps team and created the data contract documentation based on what I was seeing in the responses from the services. I wasn't on the engineering team and didn't create the services and had to figure out the data contracts through trial and error.

Comment: Gotcha.  I retried the JSON request from the datacontracts in that link and got the same result.  I was able to successfully complete the request via XML, but when trying to assign the route from ResourceSets[0].Resources[0], Resources[0] is always null.  I can see all details of the route in the XML output.

Answer (score 0):

[This thread at MSDN](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/68789486-d173-4060-9e78-bae836486a7c/resoucesets?forum=bingmapsservices) confirms, that the original classes from Microsoft are not working. But if you just generate your own classen with json2csharp.com and use that ones to deserialize it is working.

Tom